# Create an alert on div after third click count

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I create an alert after div being clicked for the third time? 
I tried some examples already, but failed on making it work.

Here's the code so far (without the count part):

```
$("div").one( "click", function() {
 $(this).css({
  background: "red",
  cursor: "auto",
 });
 $(this).append( "0" );
 $("span").append( "0" );
});
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7gosayyo/

Answer (score 1):

Need to use some JavaScript to keep track of how many times it has been clicked.

```
<button onclick="clicking()>Click me</button> 


var nClicks    = 0;
var nMaxClicks = 3;

function Clicking() {
    // increment the counter each time item is clicked
    nClick++;

    // On the 3rd click....
    if (nClicks == nMaxClicks){
       // Enter code for thing you are looking to do
       alert("Max clicks hit! " + nClicks);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

We assign a new property to the div which holds our times it got clicked (to save an extra global variable). Once it is three times we display our alert message.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function clickMe(e){
                e.clicked = (e.clicked || 0) + 1;

                if (e.clicked === 3) alert('Three times'); //Replace with (e.clicked % 3 === 0) if required.
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div onclick = 'clickMe(this)'>Click me three times</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to  get the alert on each third click (so also on sixth, ninth, ..) replace the line with this:

```
if (e.clicked % 3 === 0) alert('Three times');
```

## Edit

Added a Fiddle on request:
https://jsfiddle.net/19jy296L/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

http://jsfiddle.net/b1h4y9xL/

```
var click_count = 0;

$("div").on( "click", function() {
  click_count++;
   $(this).css({
    background: "red",
    cursor: "auto",
  });
  $(this).append( "0" );
  $( "span" ).append( "0" );
    if(click_count == 3){
        click_count = 0;
        alert('You have clicked three times!');
    }
});
```

You can just keep track of how many times a box has been clicked in a variable, and reset it when it's at three. Then every time you click, it just checks if you have gotten your three clicks or not.

Comment: I think this will work with what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `css` method, add a "clicked" class.

You can then check to see if there are three instances of that class:

```
.clicked {
  background: red;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```js
$("div").one( "click", function() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  $(this).append( "0" );
  $( "span" ).append( "0" );
  if($('div.clicked').length===3) {
    alert("Third time's the charm");
  }
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    background: green;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
p {
    color: red;
}

.clicked {
  background: red;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click 3 squares...</p>
<span>$</span>

<br>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @nattienatz want to get the third click on the same div, not on all div

Comment: @vasilenicusor, it's a bit ambiguous, especially since there's a `one` instead on `on` method.  Let's see how OP responds.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few methods to accomplish this, one is to add a class to the clicked divs and then count how many divs have the class:
[As demonstrated here](https://jsfiddle.net/umssrjLd/1/)

```
$("div").one( "click", function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    $(this).append( "0" );
    $( "span" ).append( "0" );

    if( $('div.clicked').length == 3 ) {
        alert('hello!');
    }
});
```

Another is set a variable outside of the .one() function and increment it each time it is executed, check if the variable is equal to three, and display the alert if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
var ctr = 0;
$("div").on( "click", function() {
   $(this).css({
      background: "red",
      cursor: "auto",
   });
   $(this).append( "0" );
   $( "span" ).append( "0" );
   ctr++;
   if(ctr >= 3){
   alert("Clicked 3 times");
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to allow each square to be clicked a maximum of three times you can use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to keep track of the remaining clicks for each square as in the following example.

```
$("div").each(function (index, currentDiv) {
    $(currentDiv).on("click", (function () {
        var clicksRemaining = 3;

        return function () {
            if (!clicksRemaining) {
                alert("You cannot click this square anymore.");
                return;
            }

            clicksRemaining -= 1;
            $(this).addClass("clicked");
            $(this).append("0");
            $("span").append("0");
        }
    })());
});
```

If you are wanting to allow a maximum of three clicks between all squares you can use the following code.

```
var clicksRemaining = 3;

$("div").on("click", function () {
    if (!clicksRemaining) {
        alert("You cannot click this square anymore.");
        return;
    }

    clicksRemaining -= 1;
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    $(this).append("0");
    $("span").append("0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution , based on class info attached to element on every click. You can trigger event on any click , third, fourth, fifth and so on by adding a class in var `classes` and check if the element has the specific class for the number of clicks or by monitoring the position of the current class in array .
The name of class from  variable `classes` can be any string,you can choose any naming convention, but the number of classes from `class` determine the maximum number of click which can be monitored

```
$('div').click(function () {
    var classes = ['first_click','second_click','third_click'];
    this.className = classes[($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1)%classes.length];   
    if ($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1 == 2){
       alert("second_click");        
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('third_click')){
       alert("third click");        
    }

    $(this).append($.inArray(this.className, classes)+1);
    $( "span" ).append( $.inArray(this.className, classes)+1);
});
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/mzyv1gdf/4/)